# How to customize elementary OS Guest session

Tags: language, settings

Got elementary OS installed at the local **Neighbors House** after shifting the original GPU, RAM and finally a defective motherboard. Yeah ':-p Will hopefully serve as a demo box for people around.

To achieve that I need to customize the Guest session, particularly the language, but am stuck half-way.
Your ideas are welcome!

EDIT: screenshot of the *partial* (very incomplete) result with the settings below:

[image: Eos Guest account partial localization]

/etc/default/locale

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fr_FR.UTF-8:en_US
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER=A4LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

$ locale

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fr_FR
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

$ dpkg --list|grep language

```
ii  language-pack-en                           1:14.04+20150219   all      translation updates for language English
ii  language-pack-en-base                      1:14.04+20150219   all      translations for language English
ii  language-pack-fr                           1:14.04+20140707   all      translation updates for language French
ii  language-pack-fr-base                      1:14.04+20140707   all      translations for language French
ii  language-pack-gnome-en                     1:14.04+20150219   all      GNOME translation updates for language English
ii  language-pack-gnome-en-base                1:14.04+20150219   all      GNOME translations for language English
ii  language-pack-gnome-fr                     1:14.04+20140707   all      GNOME translation updates for language French
ii  language-pack-gnome-fr-base                1:14.04+20140707   all      GNOME translations for language French
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to **System Settings** > **Language and Region**. Click unblock and select your language and click **Set Language**.

Reboot

Comment: Thank you @Suici Doga, but clicking unblock while in the Guest session does not work: stay locked. Maybe I'm missing something? Also if that worked, do you know whether it would keep the locale for the next guest session?

Answer (score 0):

The reponse to the question [how to customize guest session](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9069/how-can-i-have-the-same-applications-in-the-dock-for-the-guest-session-as-i-have) should help you to customize your guest session.

You might want to create a new test user, customize **System Settings > Language and Region** and **Set Language** as suggested by Suici Doga and copy these files to `/etc/guest-session/skel`.